# Update a collection from another takes too long

Tags: mongodb

I have this script:

```
db.getCollection('A').find({}).forEach(function(obj){
    db.aaa.insert({ "id": obj._id.valueOf() });
});
```

The problem is that it takes a very long time to be executed.
Do you have any idea of how to make this faster?
Thanks!

Comment: You want to update or replace whole collection `aaa`? Replace could be done faster though

Comment: The collection `aaa` is empty

Comment: If you only want to populate collection `aaa` from the `A`, there's a quicker way via aggregation

Comment: Great :) how can I do that?

Comment: But what exactly you want to put to collection `aaa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid slow insert performance with using the **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods)** API that streamlines your insert operations by sending them in bulk, and even better, it gives you real feedback about what succeeded and what failed.

*MongoDB version 3.2 and greater:*

```
var ops = [];
db.getCollection('A').find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "insertOne": {
            "document": { "id": doc._id.valueOf() }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 500 ) {
        db.getCollection('aaa').bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
});

if (ops.length > 0)  
    db.getCollection('aaa').bulkWrite(ops);
```

---

*MongoDB versions >= 2.6 and < 3.2:* Use the [Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulk-methods)

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('aaa').initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.getCollection('A').forEach(function (doc) {    
    bulk.insert({ "id": doc._id.valueOf() });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        // Execute per 500 operations
        bulk.execute(); 
        // re-initialize every 500 update statements
        bulk = db.getCollection('aaa').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})
// Clean up remaining queue
if (counter % 500 !== 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the aggregation API:

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([
   {$match: {}},
   {$project: {
       id: {
           $toString: "$_id" // Added in mongo 4.0
      }
   }},
   {$out: 'aaa'} // This will override existing collections, use it wisely
])
```

Comment: You want to put ObjectId as String to `aaa`? Why not let it still be ObjectId?

Comment: Hard to explain. Let's say that's what I was asked to do by my boss :)